# Wilkinson Notation in MATLAB for Within-Subjects ranova

Tags: repeated-measures, matlab

I'm trying to wrap my head around [Wilkinson Notation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/wilkinson-notation.html) without much success.

I have data that looks similar to the following table:

[image: the data].

Each row is a participant, tested under three different conditions in a within-subjects study.

I am trying to figure out how to use [ranova](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/repeatedmeasuresmodel.ranova.html) with this data to see whether these conditions are statistically different. It seems I first have to create a [repeated measures model](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/repeatedmeasuresmodel-class.html) with something like

```
rm = fitrm(t,'Condition1-Condition4~Participant');
```

But this sounds like the participant is what I am testing. I want to test the conditions instead. I do not know how to write it with Wilkinson Notation, or whether it is even possible with data formatted like mine.

Could you let me know how I can create a repeated measures model with my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is for future reference. I verified the outputs by comparing them to outputs from SPSS.

```
rm = fitrm(t,'Condition1-Condition3~1');

r = ranova(rm);

multcompare(rm, 'Time', 'ComparisonType', 'dunn-sidak')
```

Comment: +1 for taking the time to answer your own question and assist future users. Having said that, this is not "standard" Wilkinson notation. As much as I appreciate MATLAB's and R's linear mixed model capabilities, the original paper does not cover more complex experimental designs (somewhat unfortunately but expectedly).